# What are the requirements to make a Swift class and it's members be usable in Obj-C code?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Since this is nowhere documented AFAIK and I have seen problems with Swift code that cannot be bridged to Obj-C I'd like to open a thread to collect all informations regarding compatibility, work arounds and other tips here.

1. Classes must be marked with the @objc() annotation to make them available.
2. `inout` as well as `var` parameters are not supported and will cause the bridging header generation to simply ignore that function.
3. Tuples are not supported, neither as parameter nor as return value.
4. Closures are not supported, neither as parameter nor as return value.
5. Structures are not supported, neither as parameter nor as return value.

Anything more?

Comment: Have you looked closely at the Xcode 6.3 Beta / Swift 1.2 changes? I know they made some Objective C as well as Swift <-> Objective C enhancements and probably will continue to do so.  Remember, this stuff is still in Beta.

Comment: It's already documented right here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/

Comment: @AndrewKnoll I don't see many useful details there. Just try to find a list that e.g. contains ***inout***